# Tell directive to using different template based on scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a directive called, tagFor, which generate appropriate based on data that passed through attribute, for example.

```
<tag-for source="{{link}} ng-repeat="link in links"></tag-for>
```

By given `links` to be array which has 2 elements, http://example.com/image.jpg and http://example.com/video.mp4

When `link` is image url, which is http://example.com/image.jpg, the result would be `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />`

But when `link` is a video url, the result would be `<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="http://example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`

I try to use `compile` function in directive but I cannot get value of `link` to tell directive to return appropriate template.

Please help.

Comment: You should look at `ng-include`, it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in the link function just fine,  all you will do is compile the video or img templates and append them

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjiZjIZVTamswxFYAvof?p=preview)

```
app.directive('tagFor', function($compile, $timeout) {

  var video = '<iframe width="340" height="280" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  var image = '<div><img ng-src="{{link.url}}" width="340" height="280"/></div>';

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      link: '=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<div>{{link.type}}</div>',
    transclude: true,

    compile: function(tElem, tAttr) {
      //this is just the link func
      return function(scope, el, attr, ctrl, trans) {
        if (scope.link.type == 'video') {
          var vid = $compile(video)(scope);
          el.append(vid);    
        } else if (scope.link.type == 'image') {
          var img = $compile(image)(scope);
          el.append(img);
        }

      }
    }

  };

});
```

Comment: Great for `$compile` function