# Dynamic templates rendered using directive scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to find a way to render forms with different controls based on a **Type** variable specified in a JSON document. This form is going to be generated from user input, so we don't know what question types we need to render. We will define what the types are, but they can come in any order from the user.

```
{
  "Name": "Getting to know you.",
  "Id": "870tVcee8irPLdhi14fSZw==",
  "Controls": [
      {
          "Type": "Text",
          "Label": "First Name",
          "Id": "vF4z8YcSlpJGsF9fDw5TpA==", 
          "Color": "FFFFFF",
          "Required": "True",
          "Validaion": "False",
          "ValidationRegEx": "",
          "ErrorText": ""
      },
      {
          "Type": "Picklist",
          "Label": "Last Name",
          "Id": "vF4z8YcSlpJGsF9fDw5TpA==",
          "Color": "#CCCCCC",
          "Required": "True",
          "Validaion": "False",
          "ValidationRegEx": "",
          "ErrorText": "",
          "PicklistVals": ["1","3","5"]
      }
   ]
}
```

The directive needs to read the control type, then pass that to the directive to figure out what template to render.

```
<div ng-repeat="control in section.Controls">
    <input-parser ele="{{control}}"></input-parser>
</div>  


app.directive('inputParser', function() {

    function getTemplate (control) {
        var template = '';
        switch(control.Type) {
            case 'Text':
                template = '<form style="color:' + control.Color + '">template2</form>';
                break;
            case 'Picklist':
                template = '<form style="color:' + control.Color + '">template2</form>';
                break;
        }
        return template;
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            control: '@'
        },
        template: function() {
            return getTemplate(control));
        }
    }
```

**Two questions:**

1. Can you access scope variables in the template attribute of a directive that are loaded dynamically ? I can only seem to hard code them because the bindings are not set before the directive if parsed.
2. Is this a good way to render dynamic templates that need to need to access information passed into the directive. Should I just access the root scope and forget the scope variables?

Comment: I just answered this 1 yesterday with this - http://plnkr.co/edit/yjiZjIZVTamswxFYAvof?p=preview. I find the SO link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773723/tell-directive-to-using-different-template-based-on-scope-variable/26775053

Answer (score 0):

If your `input-parser` directive simply renders the form and does nothing else then how about consider using `ng-include` instead, and place all your templates as a partial.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZ5jGoyYYLn9QnBHjFsX?p=preview)**

```
<ng-include ng-repeat="control in section.Controls" src="control.type + '.html'"></ng-include>
```

But if your `input-parser` directive does have some sort of behavior that you want to share across all your templates, then you can use the `ng-include` above as a template instead.

***Javascript***

```
  .directive('inputParser', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        control: '='
      },
      template: '<ng-include src="\'form\' + control.type + \'.html\'"></ng-include>'

      // controller: function() {}, // attach your controller behaviour
      // link: function() {} // attach your element behaviour
    };
  });
```

***HTML***

```
<input-parser ng-repeat="control in section.Controls" control="control"></input-parser>
```